# Чекбокс и див поверх него

Tags: html, css

Всем привет.

На странице есть инпут типа чекбокс и следующий элемент это див(размер дива почти одинаков с размером чекбокса) который с помощью стилей css(обычный margin-left) смещен на место этого чекбокса и перекрывает его.

Когда я кликаю по чекбоксу то галочка не устанавливается.

Собственно вопрос:
Как сделать так чтобы при кликании на чекбокс галочка ставилась, чтобы можно было щелкнуть через див грубо говоря, который перекрывает его(у этого дива иконка в background).

Возможно ли такое с помощью css?

Comment: Используйте label вместо div.

Comment: Не помогает

Comment: `<label><input type="checkbox" style="position:absolute;left: -200%;" ><div>test</div></label>`

Comment: @eicto  я не совсем понял как, но это работает

Comment: @eicto спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пояснения к коду:
Здесь используются две возможности:

1. При клике на label (если у него есть атрибут for со значением равным id чекбокса) чекбокс тоже кликается.
2. Если нужно взять через CSS выбранный чекбокс, то можно использовать :checked

Далее просто скрываем сам чекбокс и стилизуем label как чекбокс. И все.

Стили:

```
ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

ul li input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  background-color: blue;
}

ul li label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: gainsboro;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input id="styled-checkbox" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="styled-checkbox"></label>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

P.S. [демо](http://jsbin.com/oxajANiN/1/) - label можно поставить и перед чекбоксом, в этом случае нужно заменить + на ~. Если нужно использовать в label текст, то просто увеличиваем его ширину и используем background-image с позиционированием скраю.

Comment: @Lucky Спасибо!